# 'yo office' not responding after a long time

Tags: office365, yeoman, office-addins, office-js, yo

I am following the instructions here https://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins#selectapp to make my first MS office powerpoint addin.

I installed the yeoman generator and ran this command `yo office`

```
yo office                                                                                                                                    ⏎

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │   Welcome to the Office  │
    |--(o)--|    │   Project generator, by  │
   `---------´   │ @OfficeDev! Let's create │
    ( _´U`_ )    │    a project together!   │
    /___A___\   /╰──────────────────────────╯
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? Project name (display name):  myHelloWorldAddin
? Root folder of project? Default to current directory
 (/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/ppt), or specify relative path
 from current (src / public):  .
? Office project type: Task Pane Add-in
? Supported Office applications: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to inverse selection)Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote, Project
? Technology to use: HTML, CSS & JavaScript
   create bower.json
   create package.json
   create tsd.json
   create .bowerrc
   create gulpfile.js
   create content/Office.css
   create images/close.png
   create images/logo-filled.png
   create scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js
   create jsconfig.json
   create tsconfig.json
   create manifest-myhelloworldaddin.xml
   create manifest.xsd
   create app/app.css
   create app/app.js
   create app/home/home.html
   create app/home/home.css
   create app/home/home.js
```

It stuck at the last line for a very long time (up to 15 minutes now).

How can I resolve this problem? Is there any log file I can inspect to find out the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]I just tested the generator on a different machine than my own. It ran successfully in`real 1m18.625s` with `user 0m33.462s` interaction time. Looking at where it stopped for you, the next thing yo office would do is to connect to different git remote origins and install the submodules that are required. I'd suggest quit and run yo office again. :)

Repo lives here - https://github.com/officedev/generator-office

If you are interested in debug and contribute to the generator, you can pass Node.js debug flags by running it like this:

```
# OS X / Linux
node --debug `which yo` <generator> [arguments]

# Windows
# Find the path to the yo binary in Command Prompt
where yo
# Or find the path to the yo binary in PowerShell
get-command yo
# Would be something like C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo
# Use this path to derive yo cli.js file
# C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
node --debug <path to yo cli.js> <generator> [arguments]
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked a lot behind a lot of restrictions of all kind, enterprise environments are not easy. Find below all my list of recommendations:

- Verify proxies, npm doesn't use the proxy by default, set proxy and http-proxy to your company's one
- Verify the strict ssl flag is set fo false which mostly always makes the download fail (classic problem of traffic between public/private networks)
- Verify the registry is correctly set in npm to use (mostly always) registry.npmjs.org

I also experienced several issues depending on the node version and npm version. I cannot control most of the time the version I use.
I had more luck understanding the underlying problems when I did run the debug mode mentioned before. The commands in the previous response are deprecated and some of them changed but pretty much you can:

1. Find where yo is installed with 'where yo'
2. Go to the folder and locate the yo module which is in the [base folder]\lib\cli.js
3. Execute it with node --inspect [full path to cli] [your parameters]

Every problem arises immediately using this method.